# Citing 2 nearly identical article names from the newspaper, APA 7th edition

Tags: writing, citation-style

I seem to be at an edge case.  I have two websites to cite,  [NYT Report Card NCF](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/college-mobility/new-college-of-florida) and [NYT Report Card YU](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/college-mobility/yeshiva-university)

They are both effectively from the same "article",  drawing on data from [This project](https://opportunityinsights.org/paper/mobilityreportcards/) to present it in a user friendly fashion.  From what I can tell, for a website of a newspaper with no author, I am supposed to cite it via the first 1-3 words of the title. "Economic Diversity and...", whatever makes it clear.  The problem is the distinguishing factor between the two different article "names" isn't until the end,  even though the articles do have different names (as they end with "at **Name of school here**").

My current inclination is to treat them as you would a same author/same year and distinguish them by (2017a) and (2017b).  However,  my first thought was to instead refer to the articles individually, citing them as "Economic...New College".  This would fit the 3 or less words and be perfectly distinct to reference them in my list, but violates the "use words from the start rule".

Should I be using one of these two options, or something else?

My actual current paper has in its citations (can't figure out the hanging tabs here, but they are in regular paper) and my citations are (Economic Diversity, 2017a), etc.

> Economic diversity and student outcomes at Yeshiva University (2017a). New York Times,
> https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/college-mobility/yeshiva-university

> Economic diversity and student outcomes at New College of Florida (2017b). New York Times,
> https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/college-mobility/new-college-of-florida

Comment: As it says to "Choose one or more of the first words from the title, enough to clearly identify the article in the Reference list." and you clearly cannot achieve that with the article in question, you would either need more words, or do not take them from the beginning. The suggested solution to go the "Economic ... New College" route seems to be more elegant and more in line with the guidelines than going the other route and using more than 3 words.